# What are the sastras or Vedas or Upanishads of taxashila or Nalanda University destroyed by foreigners?

Tags: scripture, vedas, history, upanishads, india

I have heard most of the people saying some Greek, Persians etc invaded India and burnt Vedas Upanishads etc or the knowledge present in the form of books.

Why and who destroyed them?

And, what happened after that?
If they're burnt, then what are these which we are reading in the names of Vedas, sastras etc?